# Instagram Login - How do they do it without even going to the Instagram website?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I've seen some Instagram likers and other tools like follow unfollow apps, login and get access to an instagram account without redirecting to instagram's website.
I mean they have their own custom form built and they ask us to login with our instagram innit.

How do they do that? Does Instagram API allow that? And how do they beat the limit? I heard that instagram has an API limit of Max 5000 calls per day and 2000 follows. But they follow like a ton of people in the same website. How'd they do it?

Below are some examples of Instagram logins that I've used my fake accounts with (I'm sure nobody wanna get their accounts hacked)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not using the official but the internal instagram API. This means that they simulate an android or iOS device and login with your credentials so instagram thinks you are logged in from a mobile device. This gives you access to all instagram features (like, follow, upload photo and video and etc)! There are a lot of unofficial instagram APIs on github that do exactly this.

They also use a proxy for each account so they stay beyond the rate limits and don't get flagged.

Comment: Yes that is one of them.